# Not able to connect to MYSQL database in open shift platform

Tags: mysql, hibernate, openshift

I'm trying to connect with Openshift MYSQL database using JPA and spring data but getting null value for host and port value (i.e. [jdbc:mysql://null:null/jbosstest1]) . below is code I'm using . In local,when I set environment varible mannually using Run >> Run Configuation.. command in eclipse then my code is working fine but it is not working in Open shift cloud .

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']}")
String host;

@Value("#{systemProperties['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']}") 
String port; 

@Bean

public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(String.format(url,host,port));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind . i'm able to resolve it using below code but not sure why SpEL was not working . thanks much !!

```
 @Value("${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}")
 String host;

 @Value("${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}") 
 String port;
```